# JSP Server Sent Events

Tags: jsp, server-sent-events

I have created two JSP where user login and write something in the text-box and click on send.Now i want that when the other user logs in he/she can see my message.I have read server sent events but still i cannot find my answer...

Qns-1 What will be in **form action** attribute ...?

Qns-2 How will **data be present in the server** once the user logs out...?

Qns-3 When the other user logs in **how will server get to know from where to get the update** automatically..??

*If possible do post the code for better understanding??*

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have mis-understood **SSE**, According to wiki Server Sent Events is ,

> Server-sent events (SSE) is a technology for where a browser gets
>   automatic updates from a server via HTTP connection. The Server-Sent
>   Events EventSource API is standardized as part of HTML5[1] by the W3C.

Main advantage of it is to get recent updates from the server without requesting it explicitly each time.

[Check this for more info](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

And also here for [Usage info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: I have read the link posted by you..but still i cannot find a code to implement this..What i m getting every where is WEB-SOCKETS and what i want is long pooling or just pooling code to implement this...

Comment: @ArpitSingh which concepts you need exactly and code for what ? here are simple [snippnets](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

Comment: what is want is when i click on submit the data should be present in the server and when another user logs in it automatically see the data posted by that user. I want a code in AJAX that can do this easily without adding any websockets

Comment: _what is want is when i click on submit the data should be present in the server _ do you mean the database server here ? `html5` web storage offers a way to store data through local storage